# How to add custom font weights to Material UI?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, material-ui

Trying to configure Material theme to use my own font and custom font weights/sizes for the Typography components. For the `fontWeight` section, I want to just be able to input `100/200/300/400/500/600/700` as options for each specific material typography variant, however, it specifically takes in a "string" and it apparently can only be `normal/bold/bolder/lighter`

And to make it worse `normal == 400` while `bold == 700` skipping over 500 and 600 which I need

```
typography: {
    fontFamily: "MyCustomFont",
    fontWeightLight: 200,
    fontWeightRegular: 400,
    fontWeightMedium: 500,
    useNextVariants: true,
    h1: {
      fontSize: "1.25rem",
      fontWeight: "bold",
      lineHeight: "1.2em"
    },
    h2: {
      fontSize: "1.75rem",
      fontWeight: "normal",
      lineHeight: "1.2em"
    },
}
```

Comment: Are you trying to style a Typography element like this: `<Typography variant="h6" color="inherit">` or are you trying to style a material-ui element that contain text?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I am using the same behavior, with numbers, tested with all the `100/200/300/400/500/600/700` and it worked as well:

```
import { MuiThemeProvider, createMuiTheme } from '@material-ui/core/styles';
import { Typography } from '@material-ui/core/';

const THEME = createMuiTheme({
  typography: {
    "fontFamily": "\"MyCustomFont\"",
    "fontSize": 20,
    "lineHeight": 1.5,
    "letterSpacing": 0.32,
    useNextVariants: true,
    suppressDeprecationWarnings: true,
    h6: {
      "fontWeight": 600,
    },
  },
});

<MuiThemeProvider theme={THEME}>
  <Typography variant="h6" color="inherit" align="center" style={{ margin: "1rem" }}>
      "Some text"
  </Typography>
</MuiThemeProvider>
```

Comment: What if we want to show google font with weight? fontWeight is not working for me.

Answer (score 7):

## The `Box` element can help. Ignore the `Typography` element.

See the code example below

```
<Box fontWeight="fontWeightLight">…
<Box fontWeight="fontWeightRegular">…
<Box fontWeight="fontWeightMedium">…
<Box fontWeight={500}>…
<Box fontWeight="fontWeightBold">…
```

[See official docs for more details](https://v4-3-3.material-ui.com/system/typography/)

Comment: Or don't ignore Typography element and use it:
`<Typography fontWeight="fontWeightBold" variant="body2" color="primary.main">`

Comment: @DirectionUnkown Where in the Material UI docs do you see that Typography has a `fontWeight` prop?

Comment: You can use all system props on Typography component, including fontWeight.
https://mui.com/components/typography/#system-props  

https://mui.com/system/properties/